# How to log all incoming packets

Tags: iptables, packets

I tried a prerouting rule to redirect incoming packets to a internal virtual IP address.

How can I log an incoming packet before it gets redirected?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 46.X.XX.XX -s 78.XX.XX.XX -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 1024: -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.10:8080
```

The following rules didn't work.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -s 0/0 -p tcp -j LOG --log-level 4
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 0/0 -s 0/0 -p tcp -j LOG --log-level 4
```

Answer (score 13):

You need the logging rule to be at the very beginning of your rules.

`# iptables -I INPUT 1 -m limit --limit 5/m -j LOG --log-prefix="iptables: dropped packets" --log-level 4`

- `-I INPUT 1` : This means append the rule to the INPUT chain at 1st place just before anything else.
- `-m limit` : This tells that we wish to use the limit matching module. Using this we can limit the logging using –limit option.
- `--limit 5/m` : Here comes the limit option we just talked about. This means we want to limit the maximum average matching rate for logging to 5 per minute. You can also specify 5/second, 40/minute, 1/hour, 3/day like that according to your environment and needs.
- `-j LOG` : This tells iptables to jump to LOG i.e write to the log file.
- `-–log-prefix` "iptables: dropped packets" : You can specify any log prefix, which will be appended to the log messages that will be written to the /var/log/messages file
- `-–log-level 4` : syslog level 4 stands for warning. You can use number from the range 0 through 7. 0 being the highest for emergency and 7 being the lowest for debug.

[src](http://web.archive.org/web/20150325103357/http://linuxdrops.com/how-to-log-iptables-firewall-packets-to-a-log-file/)

Comment: There should be a space after your --log-prefix string like so: ```--log-prefix="iptables: dropped packets "```. If not it will have something like this in the log: ```Feb 25 09:46:01 alarm kernel: iptables dropped packetsIN=eth OUT= MAC=.....```