# View - but not intercept - all IPv4 traffic to Linux computer

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, libpcap

Is there a way to view all the **IPv4** packets sent to a Linux computer?

I know I can capture the packets at the ethernet level using libpcap. This can work, but I don't really want to defragment the IPv4 packets.  Does libpcap provide this functionality and I'm just missing it?

One thing that kinda works is using a `tun` device. I can capture all the IPv4 traffic by routing all traffic to the `tun` device via something like `ip route add default via $TUN_IP dev $TUNID`. This also stops outbound traffic though, which is not what I want.

I just want to *see* the IPv4 packets, not intercept them. (Or, even better, *optionally* intercept them.)

Edit: I'm specifically looking for a programmatic interface to do this. E.g. something I can use from within a C program.

Comment: Do you have to do this in your own program? Wireshark can perform IP reassembly.

Comment: You can use iptables for this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697282/how-to-log-all-incoming-packets

Comment: "This can work, but I don't really want to defragment the IPv4 packets." - libpcap/tcpdump do not defragment the traffic. They even explicitly capture/print the fragment offsets and the DF bit. See `IP Fragmentation` in tcpdump man page.

Comment: I don't want to defragment them *myself*. I want the reassembled packets presented one after another.
See edit: Looking for a programmatic interface

Comment: I hope you do know that there is (usually) a massive amount of other IP4 traffic that is NOT routed to your computer but which is on the same set of wires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can see all the packets that arrive at your network interface. There are several options to access or view them. Here a small list of possible solutions, where the first one is the easiest and the last one the hardest to utilize:

### Wireshark

I'd say this is pretty much the standard when it comes to protocol analyzers with a GUI (uses libpcap). It has tons of options, a nice GUI, great filtering capabilities and reassembles IP datagrams. It uses libpcap and can also show the raw ethernet frame data. For example it allows you to see layer 2 packets like ARP. Furthermore you can capture the complete data arriving at your network interface in a file that can later be analyzed (also in Wireshark).

### tcpdump

Very powerful, similar features like Wireshark but a command line utility, which also uses libpcap. Can also capture/dump the complete interface traffic to a file. You can view the dumped data in Wireshark since the format is compatible.

### ngrep

This is known as the "network grep" and is similar to tcpdump but supports regular expressions (regex) to filter the payload data. It allows to save captured data in the file format supported by Wireshark and tcpdump (also uses libpcap).

### libnids

Quotation from the official git [repository](https://github.com/korczis/libnids):

"Libnids is a library that provides a functionality of one of NIDS 
(Network Intrusion Detection System) components, namely E-component. It means 
that libnids code watches all local network traffic [...] and provides convenient information on them to 
analyzing modules of NIDS. Libnids performs:

- assembly of TCP segments into TCP streams
- IP defragmentation
- TCP port scan detection"

### libpcap

Of course you can also write your own programs by using the library directly. Needless to say, this requires more efforts.

### Raw or Packet Sockets

In case you want to do all the dirty work yourself, this is the low level option, which of course also allows you to do everything you want. The tools listed above use them as a common basis. Raw sockets operate on OSI layer 3 and packet sockets on layer 2.

---

Note: This is not meant to be a complete list of available tools or options. I'm sure there are much more but these are the most common ones I can think of.

Comment: AFAIK libpcap only uses ethernet layer, I'm looking for IP layer.  AFAIK raw sockets cannot capture all IP-layer traffic, only a specific protocol.  I want to avoid having to reassemble the IP packets myself. I am looking for e.g. a C interface to do this.

Comment: Raw sockets *can* capture all IP traffic, no matter what protocol. Anyway, I updated my answer. What you are looking for is *libnids*. It's very easy to use, you just create a callback function, register it and the library passes in all defragmented IP datagrams.

Comment: How can raw sockets do that? Can you link me to a man page or explain how to create such a socket?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Raw sockets can capture all protocols but only the one you specified at the time of socket creation. The man page is here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html. Nevertheless, libnids will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. My end solution is just to reassemble the packets myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you have to make a copy of the received packet via libpcap. To be more specific, what you can do is to get packets with libpcap, that way the packets will be kind of blocked, so you need to re send them to the destination. Lets say that you want to make a Fire-Wall or something, what you should do is to have a layer that can work like getting the package and then send it to the destination, in between you can make a copy of what you got for further processes. In order to make the intercept option, you need to create some predefined rules, i.e. the ones that violates the rules will not be send again to their destination.

But that needs a lot of efforts and I don't think you want to waist your life on it.

> **Wire-shark** as mentioned by @Barmar can do the job already.
>
> If you need some kind of command line interface option I would say that "tcpdump" is one of the best monitoring tools. for example for capturing all ipv4 HTTP packets to and from port 80 the command will be:
>
> ```
> tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
> ```
>
> for more information and options see [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)

Please be specific if you need to write a program for it, then we can help  about how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a programmatic interface e.g. in a C program, to get the re-assembled IPv4 packets.  As far as I know (not far), libpcap only works at the ethernet level, so that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: well, I don't get what you mean by libpcap only works at the ethernet level. I've used it for any kind of packet transmission, send, receive, process; via wifi, cable, virtual networks etc. what else do you need?

Comment: As far as I know, libpcap captures ethernet frames, not IPv4 packets. An IPv4 packet can be fragmented across multiple ethernet frames. I do not want to have to reassemble those fragments into whole IPv4 packets. In other words, I think libpcap works at OSI model level 2, but I want an interface to level 3.